# A global math mode for matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I have the following code to produce a matrix, which works:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[cell/.style={rectangle,draw=black}, nodes in empty cells]
  \matrix[
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep =-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep = -\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={anchor=center, text height=1.3ex,text depth=0, cell},
  column 1/.style = {nodes={minimum width=1cm, fill=mlightgray}},
  column 2/.style = {nodes={minimum width=2cm}},
  column 3/.style = {nodes={minimum width=2cm}},
  column 4/.style = {nodes={minimum width=2cm}},
  row 1/.style={nodes={fill=mlightgray}}
  ] 
  {     & $3$  & $4$    & $5$    \\
    $3$ &      &        & $100$  \\
    $4$ & $-2$ & $-2.6$ & $97.4$ \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

As you can notice, all the values of the nodes are surrounded by `$` (math mode), does anyone know how to put a global math mode around the matrix, to avoid from tying `$` for each node?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `matrix of math nodes` instead of `matrix of nodes` then the node contents will be surrounded by `$` automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\colorlet{mlightgray}{gray!20}

\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[cell/.style={rectangle,draw=black}, nodes in empty cells]
  \matrix[
  matrix of math nodes,
  row sep =-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep = -\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={anchor=center,minimum width=2cm, text height=1.3ex,text depth=0, cell},
  column 1/.style = {nodes={minimum width=1cm, fill=mlightgray}},
  %column 2/.style = {nodes={minimum width=2cm}},
%  column 3/.style = {nodes={minimum width=2cm}},
%  column 4/.style = {nodes={minimum width=2cm}},
  row 1/.style={nodes={fill=mlightgray}}
  ]
  {     & 3  & 4    & 5    \\
    3 &      &        & 100  \\
    4 & -2 & -2.6 & 97.4 \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So simple and intuitive.